# Python Tornado TCPServer - TCPClient alternative to interface with other objects through Queues?

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

I have a Tornado TCPServer which is acting as a "bridge" between two Python programs on different computers that need to exchange data (streaming & files) and commands. There is only ever one client at a time. Since the TCPServer runs using IOLoop I have it in a separate thread to avoid blocking other server actions.

Commands are received as strings from reading the TCP connection and are put in a Queue that can be accessed in both the TCPServer thread and the outer Python thread. There is an additional Queue for sending data back to the TCPServer after a command is interpreted and executed in the outer Python thread. This arrangement is mirrored on the client side with its TCPClient as well. Each Queue is used as one-directional.

Example simplified flowchart:

[image: Flowchart]

My questions:

- Queues are very limited in the sense that there is no relation between the request and the response (i.e. two requests submitted at once could get each-other's responses if one queue is used). Other than making a list of queues and routing commands/responses through them, are there good alternatives for parallel, cross-thread communication?
- I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel and I imagine this is not a totally unique
  use-case. Are there alternatives to this TCP-to-Queue routing?

Comment: Consider using similar concepts golang uses:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130986/python-equivalent-of-golangs-select-on-channels

Answer (score 0):

Adding a partial answer to address the potential cross-communication of requests and responses in one Queue:

```
class OnDemandQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OnDemandQueue, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Create and share new temporary queues as-needed via a single existing queue

    def get_queue(self):
        send = Queue()
        receive = Queue()
        # Remote reference
        self.put_nowait([receive, send])
        # Local reference
        return [send, receive]
```

One or two instances of `OnDemandQueue` is/are shared across threads, and any time a new command-response pair is needed a new Queue pair is generated and shared via `get_queue`. This keeps everything nicely segregated and the pairs can be maintained as long as they are needed, then cleanly discarded.

In typical use a listener is needed to watch for new items in the shared `OnDemandQueue`, then determine what to do with the resulting Queue pair. While communication is bidirectional through the `get_queue` pair, the
`OnDemandQueue` itself is treated as unidirectional due to the listener, so two instances may be needed.

Comment: How do you remove those queues from the memory - how do you clean up?

Comment: My process: 1. Pair is created and made available in OnDemandQueue. 2. Listener gets the pair, which removes it from the OnDemandQueue. 3. Listener/worker thread evaluates the contents of the pair (waiting for/sending response if needed). 4. The pair is no longer needed and can be automatically garbage-collected. No references to the pair were stored during this process, they were only passed as function arguments.