# python multiprocessing pipes how to call callback function if child process sent data through pipe?

Tags: python, callback, multiprocessing, pipe, recv

Is any callback function exists in python 3 to receive data from child processes without listening to them through Process.recv() or any other block-function?

I need that because I have many child processes which can send data to parent process and I don't know how to listen all child processes in same time; and I guess callback function is better instead of infinite loops like

```
while True:
    if self.child_pipe.poll(None):
```

Comment: Maybe you want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123855/select-on-multiple-python-multiprocessing-queues

Comment: You mean I should use queues for that instead of pipes?

Comment: Yes. Queues will communicate via the pipes. You can the select the pipes and get new elements out of the Queues.

Comment: One more question then - I have a processes which is not just parallel workers - it is different child processes that can do different actions on the same data that they may receive from pipe/queue, but if I adapt my code to queues then child processes  must use task_queue.get() to get data from parent process, but if one of many child processes will get any task from task_queue - others will not receive that data and will not perform action. I need to pass each task from task_queue to all child processes and listen answer from them. How can I do that?

Comment: Open an new Question so that other people have a look at it.