# python: waiting on multiple objects (Queue, Lock, Condition, etc.)

Tags: python, concurrency

I'm using the Python [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) library. Works fine (subject to the Global Interpreter Lock, of course).

Now I have a condundrum. I have two separate sources of concurrency: either two [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)s, or a Queue and a [Condition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects). **How can I wait for the first one that is ready?** (They have to be separate objects since they are owned by different modular parts of my application.)

Windows has the [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function; is there something similar for Python concurrency primitives?

Comment: For the special case of `multiprocessing.Queue` refer to: [events - "select" on multiple Python multiprocessing Queues? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123855/select-on-multiple-python-multiprocessing-queues)

Answer (score 0):

There is not an already existing function that I know of that you asked about. However there is the threading.enumaerate() which *I think* just might return a list off all current **daemon** threads no matter the source. Once you have that list you could iterate over it looking for the condition you want. To set a thread as a daemon each thread has a method that can be called like thread.setDaemon(True) before the thread is started.

I cant say for sure that this is your answer. I don't have as much experience as apparently you do, but I looked this up in a book I have, The Python Standard Library by Example - by Doug Hellmann. He has 23 pages on managing concurrent operations in the section on threading and enumerate seamed to be something that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new synchronization object (queue, condition, etc.) let's call it the ready_event, and one Thread for each sync object you want to watch. Each thread waits for its sync object to be ready, when a thread's sync object is ready, the thread signals it via the ready_event. after you created and started the threads, you can wait on that ready_event.